# Why these confirmation modal is not showing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I use a template that uses bootstrap. I'm having trouble with showing a modal.

The form has a jquery validation, if everything is ok then when clicking on submit a confirmation modal should appear to ask user if he is sure he wants to store that information. If form doesn't pass validation then a simple message appears.
For the mentioned actions I build this:

```
    <form action="#" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="alert alert-error hide">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>Existen errores en el formulario. Por favor verifique.</div>
        <!-- modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Cargar Usuario</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn green" id="btnYes">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end modal -->
    </form>
```

As you can see, modal and error message has the attribute "hide"...

**the js file:**

```
var handleValidation2 = function () {
        // for more info visit the official plugin documentation: 
        // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

        var form2 = $('#form_sample_2');
        var error2 = $('.alert-error', form2);
        var success2 = $('#myModal', form2);

        //IMPORTANT: update CKEDITOR textarea with actual content before submit
        form2.on('submit', function () {
            for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
            }
        })

        form2.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                //some code
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                success2.show();
                error2.hide();
            }
            //some code
```

On this snippet, if form doesn't pass validation then error2.hide() function shows up the alert error message.

Problem comes when form passes validation when success2.show() function should show confirmation modal, but it's not doing that. Nothing appears when form is ok and I'm wondering what am I doing wrong.

Any help would be really much appreciated.

J.

Comment: First things first: does it actually make it to the submitHandler function?

Comment: @MarloC when form doesn't pass validation, error message appears successfully. In case of form success doesn't show anything. So I guess it makes it  to the submit handler function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `success2.show();` use `success2.modal('show')`

This should fix your issue

Answer (score -1):

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                success2.removeAttr('aria-hidden');
                success2.show();
                error2.hide();
}
```

do u try to remove att aria-hidded. hope that work for u